# Congrats to Bhargav Rao on 500k handled flags!

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation, moderators

It's not often we highlight moderators, but [Bhargav Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099593/bhargav-rao) has hit a milestone: he's hit 500k on the all-time handled flags chart (it's a moderator-only page, if you're wondering). Flag handling is not very visible to the wider community (and they're not all a moderator does), but they are an important part of what moderators do. Bhargav has shown a serious dedication to site moderation hitting this number.

[image: Bhargav at 500k]

That's a pace of about 100k per year (he was [elected in Nov 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/election/8)). Well done!

I should note that not too far behind would be [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) at about 460k handled flags. [ChrisF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) has over 200k and [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson) just under that. All are noteworthy as well.

Comment: I see his name a lot above deleted link-only answers and other non-answers. Well done! On to one million!

Comment: Yea, you can make it! (You know, flags aren't going to mark themselves helpful or decline themselves...)

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Unless you’re using a script… And of course there _are_ a few cases where flags get automatically approved, e.g. six spam flags or flagging a “Thank you” comment as _no longer needed_…

Comment: 100k/year=275 a day on average?!?! Amazing

Comment: Marking a flag declined isn't difficult. The interesting statistic is: How many complaints did he get? ... It better be pretty high as well ;)

Comment: I'll get back at it and going to make my best to help Bhargav reach 1M flags.

Comment: Unbelievable! *heading to flag more to make him reach 1m*

Comment: 400 a day on average ATM. Lots of catching up to do :)

Comment: It's a great achievement, but handling 275 flags per day is a strong signal that this site might have a problem with low-quality contributions. We shouldn't have to put so much workload on moderators.

Comment: Tipping my hat to Bhargav!

Comment: @Dharman if I'm reading correctly, most of those are comment flags (the sum doesn't match, unless we are missing one column).

Comment: @Dharman "might"? Good one :D

Comment: @Braiam: the system counts one flag per *post* on which you remove flagged comments (or handle any other flag on). So a post with a custom flag and 20 comments flagged for removal -> 1 flag handled, 20 comments deleted. Plus, the comment counter also includes comments that were not explicitly flagged. One post, 300 comments, *purge all*, and the comments deleted counter goes up by 300. The numbers are all.. futzy that way. Basically: **number of flags == number of unique posts on which we handled *one or more* flags.**

Comment: @Dharman: Bhargav, like me before him, likes to pick up the bulk of the flags every day (I no longer have the time to do so most days). We are all volunteers, and we all have specialisms, and Bhargav is our flag-tornado. In the past 3 months, he handled more than double the number of flags that ChrisF and me (the next two largest handlers), combined.

Comment: The title should be _“Bravo, Bhargav Rao …”_.

Comment: I still remember the time I said to Bhargav - "oh come on - you should run for election - you'll be great at it" and he was "I'm not really sure about it". Kept nudging and he gave in  and won an election and look where we are now. I knew he'd be great but the dedication and care he shows for this site and astronomically out of this world flag handling is beyond words. Think that nudge might have turned out okay after all, hey BR? :p

Comment: I have the Marshal badge for raising 500 helpful flags, so I really value the idea of 500,000 comments that no one has to read and go "huh?" Thanks so much for making the flag system work.

Comment: @Braiam: Also, a lot of question and answer flags are able to be handled via the standard review queues (e.g., _Low Quality Answers_, _Close Votes_) and don't require moderator attention. By contrast, _every_ comment flag requires moderator attention. I've certainly flagged far more comments than I've had to flag posts for being either _Spam_, _Very Low Quality_, or _Rude or Abusive_.

Comment: @JeremyCaney Do _no longer needed_ flags against “Thank you” comments also require moderator attention, even if they disappear immediately?

Comment: @SebastianSimon: Thats a good caveat to point out. Obviously not if they fall under the criteria to be deleted immediately, no.

Comment: Rarely can we see such talented and hardworking people! @Bhargav Rao I was also quite suprised when you mentioned you attended Bishop Cotton Boys' School because I attended Bishop Cotton Girls' school!

Comment: @VintageMind If you're looking for more alumni of BCBS, here's [one more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/579126/prashanth-chandrasekar) ;p

Comment: @Bhargav Rao The CEO of Stackoverflow!!! I guess a lot of the alumni of BCBS are quite famous. J. Jayalalithaa would probably be the most notable of all the alumni at BCGS, but I don’t know any alumni of BGBS that are currently involved in the tech industry. It’s so nice to have old school memories back! >-<

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Thank you all, I'm quite speechless to see this support. This wouldn't have been possible without you all. I also thank the entire moderator and CM team, who've been incredibly helpful throughout. I do extend my apologies for any mistakes that I've made while handling flags, and hope that you've forgiven me for them.

Thanks again, and keep flagging!

Comment: I’ve left you 200 today; see you at 1 million? :-D (“come on, back to work! *crack!* *crack!*”)

Comment: THESE are the curation metrics that we should be celebrating -- not the 1M-rep milestones where the same people are answering the same questions over and over and over.

Comment: Don't forget to thank Natty.. for raising all those flags for you :)

Comment: @mickmackusa: Yes, maybe that is the true vanity metric.

Comment: Also you got 200k delete votes! [reference](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52858283#52858283)

Comment: Thank you! You truly make this site a better place.

Comment: Couple of things - your greatest person in the world (in your profile) thingamijingy is creepy after I noticed it links to current user.  Your amazon wish list is so out of date.  You've got stuff on there from 2017 - 32gb thumbnail drive.  Congrats anyways but you may want to update your list.

Comment: The man, the myth, the legend

Comment: Thanks for your service. Always have a good impression when I see your name attached to something. :¬)

Comment: That is commitment! To put it in perspective 100k p/yr, each week its 1923, is 285 per day, everyday!!

Comment: From someone who knows what a huge amount of work this is, congratulations and thank you!

Comment: Congrats! Glad a chunk of the reason why SO's a better place is because of you!

Comment: Congrats bro! People like you make the world a better place!

Comment: Thanks so much @Bill! I do wish that I had the opportunity to be a mod alongside you, but nevertheless, you've been a role model to most of us new folks. :)

Comment: *and now the diamond is gone...*

Answer (score 47):

**Congratulations** @BhargavRao on your amazing milestone! 500K flags handled in 5 years is quite a feat.

Now let's not forget about the...

- 265K Comments deleted
- 197K Posts deleted
- 27K Posts closed
- 10K Edits

... which surprises me that no one has yet to mention that the numbers above put together *(including the 500K flags)* add up to **1 million**! *(500K + 265K + 197K + 27K + 10K = 999K so close!)*

That's a milestone on its own, though it's not clear whether any of the other moderators reached 1 million of the combined listed moderator actions *(interested to know)*. But nevertheless, it's clear that all the moderators deserve great thanks for their contributions to keeping this site *well-moderated*.

Comment: Thanks! Martijn's at 1050k, he was handling twice the number of flags than I did (in his prime). :)

Comment: Is it correct to add those numbers up? Or is 500k handled flags = 265k + 197k + 27k + 10k?

Comment: @m7913d As Martjin outlined in a comment on the question, the mod flag handled count is based on *posts*. So Bhargav has really handled far more flags than the number belies. I don't think it's unreasonable to assume it's closer to 1M.

Comment: @Machavity **I do not want to minimize,in any way,the the huge work Rao has done.** I just don't think it is relevant to add those fuzzy numbers up to create an even fuzzier "combined number of actions". As Martijn explained there is a huge overlap between those numbers. The only relevant stats are, in my humble opinion, to use the numbers as is, or to calculate the real number of flags handled. However, counting one flag per post may be relevant as an estimate of work as multiple flags (f.ex. flagging multiple comments for removal) on the same post are less work than flags on different posts.

Comment: @m7913d: I think 500k is a very respectable number, and grouping flags by post is probably a somewhat reasonable metric.  (Although probably under-counts work for picking out multiple separate comments under a post.)  For posts themselves, confirming one flag (such as spam) in a way that results in deletion will auto-confirm other flags for the same thing.  (At least that's my understanding).  So yeah, in terms of moderator workload, that's 1 unit of work looking at a post and deciding it matches a flag, regardless of the number of users reporting the same issue before a mod got to it.

Answer (score 36):

As someone whose flags Bhargav Rao has very often handled, I want to echo this post.

Flagging, by the nature of its implementation, has an anonymous feeling to it: you flag and walk away, and maybe something happens or maybe it doesn't. You don't know *who* will receive your flag message, or what the reaction will be.

Bhargav Rao's responsiveness, however, has made me feel that *we are a team,* working together to keep SO clean. Maybe it's just an illusion, but I have a sense of our having established a mutual trust. That sense is what encourages me to keep flagging.

Comment: wait... how did you know he handled your flags?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Not all moderator actions are anonymous, stuff like question closure, deletion, etc. are all visible as it says "Closed by X" or "Deleted by X", comments may get left, flag responses can occasionally identify the handler due to the way they generally speak, yada yada

Answer (score 7):

WOW!

That's incredibly much!

Just think about the figures. 100k a year means around 300 per day, assuming he is working every day, even on weekends, with this. If we assume a regular working day of 8 hours that's one flag every two minutes!