# Declined flag on an 'answer' that appears to be a sandbox post

Tags: support, declined-flags, specific-answer, not-an-answer

I don't believe there was any malicious intent [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69285945/react-image-crop-how-to-set-image-to-full-screen/69286810#69286810). The user copied some text from the question posted it in an 'answer', and also tried out posting it as a comment.

We do have a [sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox). I myself have posted in it. It's not exactly obvious on this site that such a thing exists, and I wonder if there couldn't be a custom flag message for NAA - although admittedly this is rare. Likewise, maybe a prompt for first-time posters to have a go at the sandbox if all they want to do is see how things look and feel.

In any case, since I've just gotten a warning about having a couple of recently declined flags, I figured I head off any trouble beforehand. This post is clearly not an attempt to answer the question. I've left a comment on the post, but I would like to see it properly handled.

As that post looks doomed to deletion, thought I would post a screenshot for those under 10k.

> [image]

Comment: You flagged it as NAA? These flags are often reviewed in bulk and almost no context is provided. Use them only if it's clearly not an attempt at answering a question ("Did you find a solution?", "I have a follow-up question...", "Your answer helped me so much. Thank you!"). In this case, it looks like a possible attempt at answering the question and a lack of knowledge on how to format code. A custom flag would have been better in which you explain that they just copied to OP's code without making any change (except for messing up the formatting).

Comment: From looking immediately at the answer in solitude it wouldn't be immediately obvious, if I am honest; I think the mods *only* see the answer when reviewing flags so they wouldn't see that it's just a copy pasta of the code in the question. Perhaps a custom mod flag would have gone better, where you explain it's a copy pasta and thus doesn't attempt to answer the question. Though I do agree it should be deleted, so I've downvoted the answer and voted to delete it.

Comment: BTW, when discussing posts on meta, it's a Good Idea to post a linking comment on the post (which I just did). Especially if the post's in danger of being deleted.

Comment: @JeanneDark, And I'm not blaming anybody for not picking up on the fact that this is not an answer, but just an attempt to try out the posting features on the site. I handle flags myself on a much MUCH smaller, so I have the luxury of taking my time, opening up the post, getting the context, as well as having a very solid amount of background knowledge of the overall topics in general (something practically impossible on SE).

Comment: @PM2Ring, I usually don't raise too much of a fuss about such things, but I'm very picky. There is a place on the network for sandbox stuff. It shouldn't be on the main site.

Comment: @yivi, The poster just copied some text verbatim from the question, posted it into an answer, and likewise posted it into a comment. They are trying their hand at posting (and commenting). Nothing wrong with that. But do we want posters doing that on the main site?

Comment: No, we don't, @ouflak, but like Yivi said it *looks like* an answer. This is why a custom mod flag was needed instead.

Comment: No, we don't. That's not the issue. The issue is the number of flags (and of very low quality content) and the tools at our disposal. It looks like an answer and when the flag is handled it's not clear that the code was copied from the question. For sure, that post should be deleted, but a custom flag explaining it was the better choice. Please see the examples in my first comments for post NAA flags are for).

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm spoiled on my site in that flags are so rare, we excitedly jump all into them and sort it all out. On Expats, this is Not An Answer, and if I handle the flag, I mark the flag as helpful and delete the post. I can see how, with all of the traffic on SE, that the flag handling culture would be different.

Comment: Unfortunately, just much too much very low quality content is posted on SO every day to devote so much time to every single NAA/VLQ flag. That's why they are for the most obvious cases.

Comment: Sure, it certainly belongs in a sandbox. OTOH, I can't fault a newbie for not knowing about the sandbox, or not even being aware of the concept.

Comment: If only people overall didn't leave so many "Not an Answer"-Answers, I suppose that flag would have been just fine. But.. then [Congrats to Bhargav Rao on 500k handled flags!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411441/congrats-to-bhargav-rao-on-500k-handled-flags) would have never came to be ;) If you're in doubt, there is a curating chat room, [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), where you can ask, if you want someone else's opinion on the matter before you flag.

Comment: @Larnu "I think the mods only see the answer when reviewing flags" they can view the context with a single click (questions and comments) and reviewers sadly now need a click too to be able to do this.

Comment: That doesn't change my point that when they are *reviewing* it they just see the content that was flagged, @Braiam . They have to go outside the review to see everything else.

Answer (score 8):

It **looks** like an answer, so NAA is the wrong type of flag.

A good litmus test is: If the mod needs to read the question to judge the flag, NAA is the wrong type of flag.

For these cases use a custom moderator flag clearly explaining what's the issue.

On this specific case, the answer already has two delete votes:

> [image]

So the issue will likely be dealt with without requiring mod intervention. I haven't cast the third delete vote because this meta question is still active, but I'm certain that the answer will be deleted by regular users before long.