# Using campaign URLs in external links

Tags: discussion, external-links

In some answers I would like to link to a blog post where I discuss a similar subject. It would be interesting to see what traffic is coming from Stack Overflow to my blog. Am I allowed to add Google analytics campaign URLs to my external links to track where traffic is coming from?

Of course the answer itself should be able to stand on its own without the links.

Comment: You shouldn't link to your blog very often, if at all and since you don't have any answers yet any linkage is going to appear very common. I'd avoid doing this till you've answered a substantial number of questions and then when you do mention your blog there's evidence that it's a rare event, justified by the particulars of that question.

Comment: I don't there's really an issue to use campaign URLs provided that it's really your links and not doing something fishy. But site promotion in general: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I'm not sure we have a specific policy against this, but, at the same time, I can't say I'm super enthusiastic about it, either. Is it really necessary? Can't you just check the referrer information in the header?

Comment: there ar a lot of experts with blogs here. Answer teh question and refer to yout blog aws you would all other external spircers(with execcptuion that you must show the affiliation)

Comment: I generally edit out campaign URLs if I stumble over them; there's no policy in either direction here on Stack, but it's good netiquette to not use tracking links.

Comment: @Zoe that sounds like you're applying a non-existing policy. What's your motivation for that?

Comment: @CodeCaster Absolutely hating unnecessary tracking. Not gonna get into a rollback war over it, but there's nothing saying I can't remove it either.

Comment: @Zoe I agree with you that campaign/affiliate links in URLs is just bad form/ethics. It's not banned but I frown upon people using it, and will typically edit it out as (1) it does not alter the original link target and (2) it does not alter the intentions of pointing the user to the right resource.

Comment: @Zoe I hate tracking as much as the next person, but my question was specifically about the policy (and I've asked a [moderator questionnaire question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411988/2021-moderator-election-qa-question-collection/412112#412112) about it, but that didn't make the cut). Consider someone doesn't like links to [whatever site] for [whatever reason], what  exactly makes it allowed for them to edit all those links to point to, for example, the Internet Archive, given there's no prior discussion about that?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm sus we're talking about two different things, but tracking links are usually just regular links with appended meta information. Removing that from the link doesn't actually alter the link or the content - it just removes legitimately unnecessary tracking that doesn't actually have any value to the end user. Examples include the sharing method, fbclid, source, etc. - i.e. not changing what the link points to, but removing tracking information. If it's a URL shortener, we have policies on those.

Comment: @Zoe my entire point is that, in lack of rules, you as the editor decided the tracking part of the URL was "legitimately unnecessary", while there is no regulated basis for that.

Comment: @CodeCaster there is no "lack of rules" on that matter. A general guidance and [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260778/11407695) has always been "Anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise and should be removed". Campaign URLs, unless the post is *specifically* about analytics, add *zero* relevant information and are thus just creepy noise editors are in their full right to remove. Something not being explicitly listed does not mean it is not part of the rule or guidance. Unless you want to argue that tracking URLs add something of value [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] to *the reader* of a given post, I suggest not accusing someone of wrongdoing based on that *especially* given that the said individual is currently a candidate in moderator election.

Comment: @Oleg yes, I get that, but I'm being the devil's advocate here with a slightly serious undertone. I'll try once more. What if I unilaterally decide I don't like slugs ("using-campaign-urls-in-external-links" in the current URL) and start editing those out of links in posts, just because I don't like waste of bandwidth (which these comments are quickly proving to become)? I am asking what exactly they base their behavior on, and "general guidance", "consensus" and "netiquette" don't mean that much to me in that regard.

Comment: @Oleg I am not accusing anyone, I am asking questions. Whether or not a user has nominated themselves for moderator might cause them to come under greater scrutiny than the average user is irrelevant and not the case here.

Comment: @CodeCaster to clarify my point above too - a certain case does not have to be explicitly specified to be actionable if it satisfies what we have as a general consensus and guidance for editors (to which I linked, but I can also link to the FAQ for editing for a more "official" resource). Of course we should decide on a case-by-case basis whether something is fluff or not, but there is a *guideline* for making such decisions "anything that is not relevant to the question/post is noise". So to decide whether or not to remove referrals from a post one just needs to answer one thing: [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] "does this add any value for the reader?" and that is it. Arguing that unless it is explicitly stated that it is not allowed to add referrals to links is akin to arguing that someone did not commit manslaughter because "sharp objects" are not explicitly listed. That's my point. And as for the nomination - they are not exempt from scrutiny, but it implies the scrutiny is *valid* in the first place, and in this particular case I consider it to be invalid but presented in a way as if Zoe is doing something wrong by removing the fluff from posts when editing, that's all I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you can add "Hello" and "Thanks" to your posts, you can add campaign URLs to your links. Their presence in posts are frowned upon, and many an editor will remove them if found while editing a post.

- Will they be automatically removed? *Unlikely.*
- Will you be banned from posting because you added them? *Probably not.*
- Will you get flowers and rewards heaped upon you for adding them? *Most assuredly not.*
- Will moderators support you if you start an edit war over their inclusion? *All signs point to No.*

<sub>Any answers regarding moderator or editor (or flower-giver) actions in regards to this subject are guesses on my part and are not binding in any way.</sub>